# Does Qt build with opengl=angle fix support for Windows clients not having opengl 2.0 support?

Tags: windows, qt, opengl, directx, pyqt5

We build a client using QtWebEngine from Python bindings. Unfortunately this client crashes on some windows systems not having native OpenGL 2.0 support (see debug below).
Should this work if I manage to compile qt on windows with opengl=angle or is this a dead road?

I already spent a whole day in trying compling qt from source on windows using msys2/mingw64 but fall from one trap into another without success and want to make sure the effort has even a chance of success...

Thanks!

P.S.: I also posted in the [Qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/79162/does-opengl-angle-fix-support-for-win-clients-not-having-opengl-2-0-support)

```
qt.qpa.gl: Basic wglCreateContext gives version 1.1
qt.qpa.gl: OpenGL version too low
qt.qpa.gl: OpenGL 2.0 entry points not found
qt.qpa.gl: GPU features: QSet("disable_d3d11", "disable_d3d9", "disable_desktopgl")
qt.qpa.gl: Disabling Desktop GL:  GpuDescription(vendorId=0x0, deviceId=0x0, subSysId=0x0, revision=0, driver: "vm3dum64.dll", version=7.14.1.1233, "R
DPDD Chained DD")
qt.qpa.gl: Disabling D3D11:  GpuDescription(vendorId=0x0, deviceId=0x0, subSysId=0x0, revision=0, driver: "vm3dum64.dll", version=7.14.1.1233, "RDPDD
Chained DD")
qt.qpa.gl: Disabling D3D9:  GpuDescription(vendorId=0x0, deviceId=0x0, subSysId=0x0, revision=0, driver: "vm3dum64.dll", version=7.14.1.1233, "RDPDD C
hained DD")
qt.qpa.gl: QWindowsOpenGLTester::supportedRenderers GpuDescription(vendorId=0x0, deviceId=0x0, subSysId=0x0, revision=0, driver: "vm3dum64.dll", versi
on=7.14.1.1233, "RDPDD Chained DD") renderer:  QFlags(0x8|0x20)
qt.qpa.gl: Qt: Using EGL from libEGL
qt.qpa.gl: Qt: Using OpenGL ES 2.0 from libGLESv2
qt.qpa.gl: QWindowsEGLStaticContext::create Created EGL display 0x3d409b0 v 1 . 4
qt.qpa.gl: QWindowsIntegration::createPlatformOpenGLContext QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSiz
e 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBe
havior(DefaultSwapBehavior), swapInterval 1, profile  QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile))
qt.qpa.gl: QWindowsIntegration::createPlatformOpenGLContext QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSiz
e -1, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::Swap
Behavior(DefaultSwapBehavior), swapInterval 1, profile  QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile))
qt.qpa.gl: QWindowsIntegration::createPlatformOpenGLContext QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSiz
e 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBe
havior(DefaultSwapBehavior), swapInterval 1, profile  QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile))
qt.qpa.gl: QWindowsIntegration::createPlatformOpenGLContext QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSiz
e 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBe
havior(DefaultSwapBehavior), swapInterval 1, profile  QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile))
qt.qpa.gl: QWindowsIntegration::createPlatformOpenGLContext QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSiz
e 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples 0, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SwapBe
havior(DefaultSwapBehavior), swapInterval 1, profile  QSurfaceFormat::OpenGLContextProfile(NoProfile))
QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.

Could not link shader program:
 "Failed to create D3D shaders.\n"
QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

talamaki's comment put me in the right direction:

- PyQt5 already supports the QT 5.8.x mimik by first checking for native OpenGL support and than fall back to ANGLE emulation on windows.
- unfortunatly the errorstack gives no hint what is missing on the failing systems. After doing long, long research I found the solution for all the not working windows systems: (re) install [DirectX End-User Runtimes (June 2010)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109). It seems, Windows 7 is missing some DLLs to work with ANGLE as QT expects ...

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think compiling Qt from sources with ANGLE support helps in your case. On the debug output it's visible Qt already falls back to ANGLE (libGLESv2):

```
Qt: Using OpenGL ES 2.0 from libGLESv2
```

This [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html) confirms it, assuming you are running pre-built binary packages of Qt 5.5 or newer:

> When configured with -opengl dynamic, neither Qt nor the applications
>   built using qmake will link to the opengl32 (standard desktop OpenGL)
>   or libGLESv2 (ANGLE) libraries. Instead, the appropriate library is
>   chosen at runtime. By default, Qt will determine whether the system's
>   opengl32.dll provides OpenGL 2 functions. If these are present,
>   opengl32.dll is used, otherwise the ANGLE libraries will be used.

The reason for crashing seems to be shader linking failure happening in emulated OpenGL code (ANGLE/Direct3D).

```
QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.
```

Why that happens is then a different story. First, I would update DirectX to a latest version.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. It put me in the righ direction: Installing "DirectX End-User Runtimes (June 2010)" fixed all problems!